# Work-around to get USB-C headset to work for calls (in Android smartphones)?

Tags: headphones, usb-c

It is an interesting, albeit frustrating, phenomenon of late that manufacturers of soft- and hardware these days (including Huawei, Samsung and apparently also Google) release new products which do not function as advertized:

> [I use my usb-c setup for mostly listening to hi-res music, it's
>   annoying when I get a phone call and I have to disconnect my USB-c
>   headphones to answer the call. Seriously Samsung needs to get there
>   head out of the ass and fix this problem. How can every other flagship
>   phone handle this including the OnePlus
>   6.](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s9-plus/help/usb-c-headphone-issues-t3807733)

and

> [bump. So I did some bumming around. I don't think it's the equalizer
>   that's the problem. I think the phone app is incapable of routing
>   calls through
>   USB-C.](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s8+/help/hear-calls-usb-c-headphones-t3736729)

and

> [Google acknowledges Pixel 2 USB-C headphone adapter issue, says fix
>   coming](http://piunikaweb.com/2017/11/01/users-reporting-usb-c-dongle-wi-fi-issues-pixel-2-google-asking-bug-reports/)

and

> [It’s 2018 and USB Type-C is still a
>   mess](https://www.androidauthority.com/state-of-usb-type-c-870996/)

and

> [How USB Type-C Has Failed Android Smartphone
>   Users](https://www.indiatimes.com/technology/gadgets/how-usb-type-c-has-failed-android-smartphone-users-why-apple-s-lightning-connector-is-best-334628.html)

Here's what I'm confronted with: **Huawei P10** with up-to-date software as of 3 Sep 2018, build nr. VTR-L09 8.0.0.375(C432) and "**Dialer**" app/process (?) version nr. 8.1.0.301 and **Huawei Active Noise Cancel(l)ing Earphones 3 (cm-Q3)**  where sound works and *calls through other apps like WhatsApp works* but *not* through the standard telephone app. Any ideas on how to route standard phone calls through another (trustworthy...) app?

Other than finding a viable work-around all I can do is to hope that a fix will percolate through eventually through an update...

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue. Tested it with a Honor 10 on Android 9. Working correctly there. So I guess with Android 9 it should work.

Comment: I'm on 9 on Samsung Galaxy S8 and it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Works on Samsung S10e; still doesn't work on Huawei P10 (with Android 9). Oh well, I guess the guys at Huawei have other other worries these days which *trump* this issue... :(