# How to change the pitch of the white-noise ***when placing a call*** with Samsung S10e connected to the Bose QC35ii?

Tags: bluetooth, calls, headset

### Background

*Ok, here goes:
Huawei P10 is still the best phone out there. (Only thing I miss here is an additional wide-angle lens, but hey.)
After having taking it's ten-thousandst fall the glass splintered slightly on the side and the camera is showing focus issues (which can only be "fixed" temporarily by letting it drop on a flat surface: google it...) I decided I need to look for a replacement :(
Regarding modern phones, I can't stand a notch, with the exception of the punch-hole on the side, like featured in the Samsung S10e. Thanks to Trump and the Huawei-Google-sanctions, the obvious Huawei P40 family is also out of the question.*

---

### The Problem

Hitherto, I'd use the P10 in combination with a Bluetooth-connected Bose QC35ii headset for business **calls**. Sure, there was a distinct white-noise hiss already then when initiating calls, **but now this hiss with the S10e has a different pitch** and it's driving me bonkers / bananas.

Note:

1. All devices have the **latest firmware and updates installed** (as
   per **20 Apr 2020**).
2. **No** (white-noise) hiss is present when placing a call [with another, USB-C wired
   headset](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/201134/work-around-to-get-usb-c-headset-to-work-for-calls-in-android-smartphones)
   **or** *without* a headset.
3. The hiss **starts already when dialling and continues throughout the call**.
4. Listening to **music** does **not** cause any (discernible) white-noise (irrespective of whether noise-cancelling is on or off).

Does anyone have an idea of how to change the pitch of the white-noise ***when placing a call*** with the Samsung S10e through the Bose QC35ii?

---

### Related Link(s)

https://community.bose.com/t5/Around-On-Ear-Headphones/Bose-QC-35-Firmware-4-5-2-Noise-Cancellation-Investigation/td-p/285738 (interesting read, albeit not that helpful... doesn't cover a way to turn off the "hiss")

Comment: @downvoter: care to comment?

Comment: I haven't voted (yet), but the rant doesn't make the question anything easier to answer. Care to reduce your personal opinion/rant and stick to the fact & issue only?

Comment: @AndrewT. Fact is: Huawei P10 had a much more pleasant (to me!) "hiss" than the Samsung S10e when calling via the Bose QC35ii.

Answer (score 0):

I happen to own a S10e and QC35II as well. Before I had the QC35 (version 1) and never had issues with the bluetooth. Everyting was running smooth, I had my phone and PC connected to the headset at the same time all the time.

It started with the QC35II. I cant say anything about calling with the headset, but I recognize the interference with listening to audio. Things that helped between phone-headset connection where going to 'Settings' -> 'Connections' -> 'Bluetooth' -> Next to your connected QC35 headset press settings symbol -> There are three options, turning 'Calls' and 'Acces to contacts' off helped (so leaving only Audio on).

As for desktop, go to Configuratiescherm\Hardware en geluiden\Apparaten en printers\ to properties of connected QC35II, tab Services and unselect Handsfree calling.

Third thing that helps with less interference is turning off my phone bluetooth when the headset is connected to my PC and vice versa.

You can see my tips are focussed on listening to music, however it probably works the other way around as well --> turning off audio and leaving on call-things will cause less interference for calling.